# Can't change payment callback URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, payment-gateway, payment

Facebook payment process is working on the development server.

When we change the callback to the production server it doesn't work : Facebook server never send the request, or we never receive it.

- same SSL certificate
- We tried on two different machine
- Facebook URL test page works
- If we change callback to the dev server with an alias URL it works !

https://dev01.tld.com/cgi/ps or https://dev02.tld.com/cgi/ps both pointing to the same IP are working
https://ps01.tld.com/cgi/ps pointing to another IP than dev01 never worked

Does facebook cache the IP address? 
How to change this or refresh the facebook cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found, this was a SSL problem, not the same SSL config, Facebook begin the request and abort. No log in apache.
Compare your SSL config with openssl s_client -connect ps.tld.com:443